# Ionic 5 capacitor Qr Code camera view not showing

Tags: css, webview, qr-code, capacitor, ionic5

I get blank screen when using capacitor QrCode package.

I'm using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner) to build a simple QrCode scanner
but I keep getting a black screen when calling the scan() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so when calling QrScanner.show() the webView get transparent like

```
SomeElement{
background : none transparent ;
}
```

but the thing is ionic don't use "background" instead it uses "--background" so what i did exactly is i put
this line in Android Studio QRScanner.Java line 473:

```
webView.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

in global.scss :

```
ion-app.cameraView,
ion-app.cameraView ion-content,
ion-app.cameraView .nav-decor,
ion-app.cameraView ion-page {
  background: transparent none !important;
  --background :transparent none !important;
  --ion-background-color: none; // this is important
}
```

when loading the scanner (just before QRScanner.prepare())

```
(window.document.querySelector('ion-app') as HTMLElement).classList.add('cameraView');
```

and of course when done go back to normal view

```
(window.document.querySelector('ion-app') as HTMLElement).classList.remove('cameraView');
```

Hope this help somebody